# Strava "Problem with Authorization Callback Domain"

Tags: android, api, dns, strava

I have a problem when i try to connect to strava.I don't know what to put in the ***Authorization Callback Domain***.I put localhost or 127.0.0.1

When i run the app i got the following error
[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    private static final int RQ_LOGIN = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StravaLoginButton loginButton = (StravaLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    private void login() {
        Intent intent = StravaLogin.withContext(this)
                                    .withClientID(29519)
                                    .withRedirectURI("gekon.technologypark.cz")
                                    .withApprovalPrompt(AUTO)
                                    .withAccessScope(AccessScope.VIEW_PRIVATE_WRITE)
                                    .makeIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQ_LOGIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RQ_LOGIN && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Log.d("Strava code", data.getStringExtra(RESULT_CODE));
            AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.create()
                    .debug()
                    .build();
            AuthenticationAPI api = new AuthenticationAPI(config);
            LoginResult result = api.getTokenForApp(AppCredentials.with(29519, "8d55af50a97a9f4b5269670de00bf5e6f4b9942d "))
                    .withCode(RESULT_CODE)
                    .execute();
        }
    }


}
```

I've seen that the redirectUri must be the same with the callback domain so I put **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** but i still get this error

Comment: how did you solve that problem, i am facing the exact problem , may you please help?

Answer (score 3):

You have to include `http://` in `redirect_uri` parameter; e.g. if you set `localhost` as your callback domain:

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=XXXXX&
    redirect_uri=http://localhost&
    response_type=code&
    scope=read_all,profile:read_all,activity:read_all
```

Comment: Doesn't work either.I've put [link](https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/35832462?access_token=0eb39dbc4dda5a7080bbc98d5ed8e325076d37a3) and it gets me to the json that displays my profile.I think i need to find how to change the athlete id(athlete/35832462) every time a user tries to connect with strava.because this number is my account only

Comment: if you already have an access_token you probably don't have any more problem with required_uri. last week there was an improvement in strava authentication: give a look to https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/ and https://developers.strava.com/docs/oauth-updates/

Comment: Thanks i will check it out!